# Trace replayer won't load binary debug information

Tags: ida, debugging, x86, linux

So I'm debugging a linux application with what I believe DWARF debug information on x86-64 host. Everything is working fine and as expected - the source files are loaded immediately on function breakpoint plus I can set source breakpoints and my source lines are followed.

However recently I got a segfault at some-point with my application. I decided to use the trace debugger to help me better understand what exactly happened there and I recorded the part where I think the program crashes. But surprise, surprise the Trace debugger won't switch and follow my source files and no binary debug information is present for it. Any help will be appreciated - I have no intention to try decompiling or matching my own source code.

I got ida 6.8 btw.

Trying to load the < replay > debug symbols I get some error like this:

> DWARF: Cannot determine location of DWARF info for "< replay >".